# ASP.NET Identity not "saving" updated claim

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, identity

Long story short, I use Identity and in my solution I created a custom account settings page which works fine and dandy. The problem is that I have the users `FirstName` and `LastName` in the `_Layout.cshtml`. The name is set by a custom helper method I have:

```
public static MvcHtmlString GetUsersFirstAndLastName(this HtmlHelper helper)
{
   string fullName = HttpContext.Current?.User?.Identity?.Name ?? string.Empty;

   var userIdentity = (ClaimsPrincipal)Thread.CurrentPrincipal;
   var nameClaim = identity?.FindFirst("fullname");

   if (nameClaim != null)
   {
       fullName = nameClaim.Value;
   }

   return MvcHtmlString.Create(fullName);
}
```

This method works great, until a user goes to their profile and updates their name. If they change their name from `George` to `Bob` then when they go around on my website this method still pulls their name as `George` until they log out and log back in.

So what I did to fix that was when they update their name in the account settings I added some code to remove their old `fullName` claim, and add the new one, like this:

```
var identity = User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;

// check for existing claim and remove it
var currentClaim = identity.FindFirst("fullName");
if (currentClaim != null)
   identity.RemoveClaim(existingClaim);

// add new claim
var fullName = user.FirstName + " " + user.LastName;

identity.AddClaim(new Claim("fullName", fullName));
```

With this bit of code the `_Layout` view now updates the name (in our previous example `George` will now change to `Bob`). However, the moment the click out of that view to another place on the website or the moment they refresh the page it changes right back to `George`.

Still being a bit new to identity I'm a bit puzzled why this new updated claim does not work after they click around to a different page or refresh. Any help is appreciated. :)

Comment: you can just re-issue the cookie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When adding the new claim you also needed to do this:

```
var authenticationManager = HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication;
    authenticationManager.AuthenticationResponseGrant = new AuthenticationResponseGrant(new ClaimsPrincipal(identity), new AuthenticationProperties() { IsPersistent = true });
```

So the new full code block is:

```
public static MvcHtmlString GetUsersFirstAndLastName(this HtmlHelper helper)
{
    string fullName = HttpContext.Current?.User?.Identity?.Name ?? string.Empty;

    var userIdentity = (ClaimsPrincipal)Thread.CurrentPrincipal;
    var nameClaim = identity?.FindFirst("fullname");

    var authenticationManager = HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication;
    authenticationManager.AuthenticationResponseGrant = new AuthenticationResponseGrant(new ClaimsPrincipal(identity), new AuthenticationProperties() { IsPersistent = true });
 
    if (nameClaim != null)
    {
        fullName = nameClaim.Value;
    }

    return MvcHtmlString.Create(fullName);
}
```